# socket.h (_uid32_t) error

Tags: c, sockets, struct, cygwin

Am trying my hand at sockets programming and I need some help because I can't build any of the programs I write. Whenever I try to build any sockets application, the compiler reports the following error:

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '_uid32_t'

This variable is inside a struct, which in turn is located in the header file "socket.h",  and looks like this:

```
struct ucred {
  pid_t         pid;
  __uid32_t     uid;
  __gid32_t     gid;
};
```

There aren't any other errors in the other files and this is the only error the compiler returns.

I don't know if this is of any consequence but the header file is the one that comes with cygwin because the guides and tutorials am using are on Unix sockets and am running Windows XP. Am also using Code::Blocks running a gcc compiler.

I really hope that it's possible to run a program using the Unix sockets API on Windows because I'd really hate to confine myself to winsock only. Also, most of the freely available and comprehensive tutorials on sockets and network programming use Unix sockets.

Here's the code, though I don't think it really matters because I get the exact same error no matter program as long as it's using *socket.h*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys\types.h>
#include <sys\socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa\inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int status;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: showip hostname\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;//AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

    for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p ->ai_next)
    {
        void *addr;
        char *ipver;

        //get the pointer to the address itself
        //different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
        if (p ->ai_family == AF_INET)
        {
            //IPv4
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p ->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4 ->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        }
        else//IPv6
        {
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p ->ai_addr;
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }
        //convert the IP to a string and print it;
        inet_ntop(p ->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
        printf(" %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);//free linked list

    return 0;
}
```

There's also other source code from other programs I could have added but I chose this one instead because I got it from the internet and not a textbook so anyone can look it up [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html#getaddrinfo).

Comment: Try fixing the backwards slashes in your include statements...

Answer (score 0):

Try including `<unistd.h>` and `<sys/types.h>` before your `socket.h`.

Comment: Your include statements use backslashes instead of forward slashes, what happens if you change them to /?

Edit: ah, beaten to it by R.